# Is there a way to add a prefix to all elements in array in jolt?

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I would like to add a constant prefix eg."0" to all the fields in an array.

This is the input:

```
{
  "input": [
    "1_ANY",
    "2_ANY",
    "3_ANY"
  ]
}
```

`Output:`

```
{
  "output" : [ "1", "2", "3" ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "output" : [ "01", "02", "03" ]
}
```

Spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "input": {
        "*": {
          "*_*": {
            "$(0,1)": "output"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

]
```

Is there a way I can add a constant prefix to all elements in the array of strings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add modify-overwrite-beta spec to the one you created to do the concatenation as follows:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "input": {
        "*": {
          "*_*": {
            "$(0,1)": "output"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "output": {
        "*": "=concat('0',@0)"
      }
    }
  }

]
```

Or you can do it using two shift operations as follows:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "input": {
        "*": {
          "*_*": {
            "$": "0&(1,1)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "output"
      }
    }
  }

]
```